# Does not see qr when scanning ios kotlin

Tags: ios, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to set up a function that will return a qr string, but I only got the camera display, it doesn't want to scan

```
@Composable
actual fun startScan(completion: (String) -> Unit) {
    val viewController = LocalUIViewController.current
    val captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if (captureDevice?.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) == false) {
        println("Устройство не поддерживает захват видео")
        return
    }
    val authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatusForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    when (authorizationStatus) {
        AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized -> {
            startCaptureSession(captureDevice, viewController)
        }

        AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined -> {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccessForMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) { granted: Boolean ->
                if (granted) {
                    startCaptureSession(captureDevice, viewController)
                } else {
                    println("Пользователь отказал в доступе к камере")
                }
            }
        }

        else -> {
            println("Нет разрешения на использование камеры")
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
fun startCaptureSession(captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?, viewController: UIViewController) {
    val captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    if (captureDevice != null) println("captureDevice not null") else println("captureDevice null")
    val input = captureDevice?.let {
        try {
            AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(it, null)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            println("Ошибка при создании AVCaptureDeviceInput: ${ex.message}")
            return
        }
    }

    println(input?.debugDescription ?: "NULL")

    if (input != null) {
        var qrCodeHighlightView = UIView()
        qrCodeHighlightView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        qrCodeHighlightView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor.CGColor

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.addInput(input)

        val metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        val previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = viewController.view.bounds
        previewLayer.addSublayer(qrCodeHighlightView.layer)
        captureSession.startRunning()
        println("START!")

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(
            object : NSObject(), AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegateProtocol {
                override fun captureOutput(
                    captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                    didOutputMetadataObjects: List<*>,
                    fromConnection: AVCaptureConnection
                ) {
                    println("captureOutput")
                    if (didOutputMetadataObjects.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val qrCodeValue = didOutputMetadataObjects.firstOrNull() as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
                        println(qrCodeValue?.stringValue.toString())
                        if (qrCodeValue != null) {
                            val qrCodeBounds = qrCodeValue.bounds
                            val transformedBounds = previewLayer.rectForMetadataOutputRectOfInterest(qrCodeBounds)
                            qrCodeHighlightView.layer.frame = transformedBounds
                        }
                        captureSession.stopRunning()
                        previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    }
                }
                   },
            dispatch_get_main_queue()
        )
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = mutableListOf(AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode)
        viewController.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    }
}
```

Tell me where I'm making a mistake and which libraries need to be read

```
 override fun captureOutput(
                    captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                    didOutputMetadataObjects: List<*>,
                    fromConnection: AVCaptureConnection
                ) {
                    println("captureOutput")
                    if (didOutputMetadataObjects.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val qrCodeValue = didOutputMetadataObjects.firstOrNull() as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
                        println(qrCodeValue?.stringValue.toString())
                        if (qrCodeValue != null) {
                            val qrCodeBounds = qrCodeValue.bounds
                            val transformedBounds = previewLayer.rectForMetadataOutputRectOfInterest(qrCodeBounds)
                            qrCodeHighlightView.layer.frame = transformedBounds
                        }
                        captureSession.stopRunning()
                        previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    }
                }
```

Comment: My guess is that some of the objects you create gets released right after code execution - this is default behavior for iOS memory system when you're not storing an object reference. I would've moved the code in a class which you can store with `remember`, and make sure the needed objects are stored in properties. or a view model instead of remember - not sure if they work for iOS compose